# setting default dimensions and clipping

Tags: dimensions

sorry, very new to blender,pls excuse the beginner question. Is there a way to set default clipping and dimensions in user preferences instead of in properties menu and side menu? is there a file I can edit? everytime I restart blender I need to reset the dimensions and adjust the clipping. would be good to set to a common used preference then adjust from the menus when needed. thank you for your help.

Comment: File > Defaults > Save Startup File

Answer (score 2):

1. Open a new file in Blender
2. Set any setting you want saved.
3. File > Defaults > Save Startup File

Now every new file you create will open with the saved settings.

Comment: excellent, thank you so much for the reply, really appreciate it